# Postman: How to verify the data type of the field without verifying its value?

Tags: javascript, api, testing, postman, web-api-testing

For example, API response is:
    "Test": {
      "Test1": 390,
      "Test2": "391"
}

I just want check that the Test1 returning integer value and Test2 is returning string value without verifying the actual value (ex: 390) returned by the field.

Answer (score 1):

`isNaN` returns true if the supplied argument isNotaNumber. (i.e. you want false from isNaN)

```js
var obj = { val: 12345 };
console.log(!isNaN(obj.val)); // true. its integer
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use typeof(), ie:

```
var montexte="montexte"
var monchiffre=50

console.log('texte ? ' + typeof(montexte)) // gives string
console.log('chiffre ? ' + typeof(monchiffre)) // gives number
```

hope this helps